# setTimeout method not working with ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

Here I am working on a quiz portal.
The questions are set in form of modules, i.e a module contains 5 questions first 4 are text type and 5th one is image type.

When the user registers using register.php he is taken to index.php from where he logins.

After the login he is shown a start button. On pressing the start button the qstartfunc() is called which using the xmlHTTPrequest opens qstart.php file which in response returns a question in html form.

the response is as follows

```
Response=<script>
        setTimeout(qtime,30);
    </script>
    <div>
    <form name='question'  action='#'>
        <p>Question #8: Since independence, both development and non-development expenditures have increased; the increase in the former being a little more than in the other. Non-development expenditure involves<br />

 I.      interest payments<br />

 II.    subsidies<br />

 III.   defence<br />

 IV.    irrigation

 ?
        </p>
        <input id='a' type='radio' name='ansa' value='optiona' /> I, II<br />
        <input  id='b' type='radio' name='ansa' value='optionb' /> I<br />
        <input  id='c' type='radio' name='ansa' value='optionc' /> I, II, III<br />
        <input  id='d' type='radio' name='ansa' value='optiond' /> II, III, IV<br />
        <button onclick='qreturnfunc();return false;'>Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>"
```

Now as you see i am calling the qtime() function in the setTimeout method with some time int this case 30. the qtime() method calls qreturnfunc() which responses back with a different question but the same format of response.

But the setTimeout method is not working. This piece of code intends to limit the user with this time otherwise it would submit automatically.

Everything else is working fine except the setTimeout method.

So if you guys find any error please help me out. Any criticism is even welcome..

Thanks in advance.

the link for the complete package is

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6KPYbSD1sxDU0k0QkU2YWVISWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually said what is happening though.

My guess though is that your timer is running to fast, because timers in JS take increment in milliseconds.  So 30 seconds in Javascript is 30,000 milliseconds.

edit:  what debugging are you doing?  Is the function being called?  are you checking for errors?  It sounds like you don't know what your code is or isn't doing, which could be obtained by simply adding logging and seeing how far your code gets.

Comment: It should call the function qtime() after 30 milliseconds(just suppose) and change the question but there is no change of question even after that time.
But the question does change when submit button is pressed.

Comment: right.  but are you logging to see if that function is called?  are you checking for errors in your console?  what are you doing to follow trace the execution of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
<script>
$.ready(function(){
        setTimeout(qtime,30);
});
</script>
```

Or

```
 <script>
    window.load = function(){
            setTimeout(qtime,30);
    };
 </script>
```

Unless you will have no way to be sure about your when the script is being executed.